# Can Semantic and Company coexist?

Tags: company-mode, semantic-mode

I use **company-irony** for C++ code completion. I have deleted the **company-semantic** backend from **company-backends** in my **init.el**.

Now I want to use **Semantic** and specifically the **global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode** to display current function at the top of the frame (this is useful if the function spans more than one frame). I enabled this in my init.el and it works.

So far I haven't noticed any problems with using Company and Semantic concurrently like this. Does anybody know if this might cause problems?

Comment: Try disabling `semantic-idle-completions-mode` and/or `global-semantic-idle-completions-mode`.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow when I'm back at work.

Answer (score 2):

I did run into trouble. Emacs would become unresponsive trying to complete code and at other times when I do not know what was executing. I disabled Semantic again and Emacs went back to normal again. So one clearly need to do some more configuration to run Company and Semantic concurrently, the only question is what.

Comment: Sometimes Semantic needs time to index files, for completions and etc. You could find out if that was the problem by trying Semantic without Company (it has a built-in completion feature too, although it's relatively awkward).